# Javascript: Increment array element in for loop when working with nested for loops & two dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

`matrix = [[0,1,1,2], [0,5,0,0], [2,0,3,3]]`

I wanted to iterate through this nested array and compare elements from each array to their counterpart in the other arrays i.e. compare the `5` (1th element) in the second array to the `1` (1th element) in the first array and the `0` (1th element) in the third array. I want to check if the element in the current array I'm looking at has a counterpart in one of the other arrays that equals 0.

So basically I want to compare [0][0] to [1][0] and [2][0], [0][1] to [2][1] and [3][1], and so forth, in a nested for loop.

Here's what I tried:

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    let total = 0;
    let arr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if(matrix[i][j] != 0 && matrix[i + 1][j] != 0) {
                console.log(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This part of the if statement results in an `undefined` error :
`&& matrix[i + 1][j] != 0`

In a regular array/for loop we can increment the `i` to compare the current element to the next element. How can I do this in a nested for loop when working with an array of arrays?

Comment: please add  the wanted result. does the function name reflects the purpose?

Comment: `matrix[i + 1]` will go out of bounds for `i == matrix.length`

Answer (score 0):

If the subarrays are of the same length you only have to iterate over the first subarray's elements and compare it to the their counterparts, If i understand you correctly i think this will do it for you:

```
var matrix =  [[0,1,1,2], [0,5,0,0], [2,0,3,3]]
var len = matrix[0].length
var flatArray = matrix.flat()
for(let index=0;index<len;index++){
if(flatArray[index] !== 0 && flatArray[index + len] !== 0 && flatArray[index 
+ 2*len] !== 0)
console.log(index,flatArray[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested loops, you can use [the ES6 iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and grab all iterators from internal arrays, then consume their output until finished. This can simplify how you work with the data because each iteration you only have the the current sequential item from each array:

```js
function compareAll(matrix) {
  //get all the iterators for sub-arrays
  const iterators = matrix.map(sub => sub[Symbol.iterator]());

  while(true) {
    //advance all iterators and take theur results
    let res = iterators.map(it => it.next());
    
    //terminate if any is done
    if (res.some(r => r.done)) break;
    
    //get the values
    let currentValues = res.map(({value}) => value);

    //do something with them
    const allEqual = currentValues.every(function(value) {
      return value === this;
    }, currentValues[0]);
    console.log(currentValues, allEqual);
  }
}


compareAll([[0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]]);
```